# Como redirecionar view em um controller com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma página de consulta de departamentos e nela tenho o botão cadastrar. Essa página é uma "view" que foi definida como rota e é chamada dentro de meu index.html.

Gosaria de saber como é possível ao clicar no botão cadastrar, mudar a view que estou para a de cadastro que irei utilizar.

Tenho que usar algum serviço específico do angular ?

essas são minhas rotas:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/cadastro/produtos", {
        templateUrl: 'view/consultaDeProdutos.html',
        controller: 'productRegisterController as vm'
    })

    .when("/cadastro/categorias", {
        templateUrl: 'view/consultaDeCategorias.html',
        controller: 'categoryRegisterController as vm'
    })

    .when("/cadastro/departamentos", {
        templateUrl: 'view/consultaDeDepartamentos.html',
        controller: 'departmentRegisterController as vm'
    })

    .when("/cadastro/departamentos/salvar", {
        templateUrl: 'view/cadastroDeDepartamentos.html',
        controller: 'departmentRegisterController as vm'
    })
```

Quero da rota /cadastro/departamentos ir para /cadastro/departamentos/salvar

através de um button

Comment: se tem algum código?

Comment: Sim, já adicionei na pergunta

Comment: Porque tem alias vm para todas os controller? isso não está errado?

Comment: Como assim para todos controllers ? Eu uso um alias para não usar o $scope

Comment: Henrique coloca todo o código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa usar o serviço `$location` para mudar de rotas/views.

```
app.controller('departmentRegisterController', ['$location', '$scope', function ($location,$scope) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.Cadastrar = function() {
        $location.path('/cadastro/departamentos/salvar');
    }

}]);
```

Daí no botão você pode usar assim:

```
<button ng-click="vm.Cadastrar()">Cadastrar</button>
```

---

No controller da tela de cadastro (no teu caso é o mesmo controller), você pode criar outro método para voltar para a lista de departamentos:

```
vm.ExibirListaDeDepartamentos = function() {
    $location.path('/cadastro/departamentos');
}
```

E criar um botão *Cancelar* ou *Voltar* como esse:

```
<button ng-click="vm.ExibirListaDeDepartamentos()">Cancelar</button>
```

Comment: Eu tinha tentado dessa forma também, porém não deu certo... ele entende que estou passando uma rota inexistente e cai no "othrewise" redirecionando para meu index. Sabe o por que disso?

Comment: @Henrique que estranho. Está utilizando exatamente `"/cadastro/departamentos/salvar"`? Você pode incluir o código do teu controller onde você utiliza o `$location`? Pelo menos para a view `"/cadastro/departamentos"` você consegue ir?

Comment: Funcionou Alisson, descobri um erro de sintaxe no meu index.... então esse procedimento fucionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Você acha melhor eu mudar minhas rotas e usar state do ui-router do que ngRoute ?

Comment: @Henrique o ui-router tem tudo o que o ngRoute tem e mais algumas coisas, de cabeça o mais atrativo é que o ui-router permite você usar views aninhadas, enquanto no ngRoute você só pode utilizar uma view por vez. Para apps mais simples e caso você não esteja com tempo de aprender o ui-router, use o ngRoute mesmo. Mas se você já souber ou tiver tempo, sugiro o ui-router.

Comment: Cara esse $location utiliza algum tipo e cache ? Ele ta redirecionando para a view que optei, mas qualquer mudança que faço no html não reflete na view.... E estou salvando tudo certo...

Comment: @Henrique na verdade o próprio browser por padrão guarda arquivos estáticos em cache, como css, js e html. Tente apertar CTRL + F5 e veja se funciona.